# Camera in LG UltraFine monitor, via USB-C is not detected

Tags: camera, usb-c

Using an LG UltraFine monitor with an integrated video camera via USB-C (which also charges the laptop), I am able to use the monitor, but only the laptop's camera is detected, not the camera built into the monitor.

Ubuntu 17.04, Monitor UltraFine 27md5ka